# Prove 2 maps are transverse and show a set is a manifold without boundary

Tags: analysis, manifolds

I haven't learned the concept of "transverse" yet, and it just appears in the question.

Consider two maps $$\begin{align}
f_{0}:U_{0}\to \mathbb{R}^n \\ f_{1}:U_{1}\to \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}$$ and  with $U_{0}\subset \mathbb{R}^{k_{0}}; \ U_{1}\subset \mathbb{R}^{k_{1}}$ are $2$ open sets. We say $f_{0},f_{1}$ are transverse if for all $x\in U_{0}, \ y\in U_{1}$ , with $$\begin{align}
f_{0}(x)=f_{1}(y)=p\in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}$$ we have that any vector $v\in \mathscr{T}_{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can be expressed as a sum $$\begin{align}
(p;v)=(p;Df_{0}(x)v_{0})+(p;Df_{1}(y)v_{1})
\end{align}$$ for $v_{0}\in \mathscr{T}_{x}(U_{0})$ and $v_{1}\in \mathscr{T}_{y}(U_{1})$ .

I'm asked to solve the following problems.

1 Let $$\begin{align}
\alpha :t \to (\cos t, \sin t) 
\end{align}$$ and for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$ , $$\begin{align}
f_{r}:t\to (t,r)
\end{align}$$ I'm asked to prove $\alpha$ and $f_{r}$ are transverse if and only if $r\ne \pm 1$

2 $f_{0}:U_{0}\to \mathbb{R}^n  \ \ \  f_{1}:U_{1}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ , and consider the set $$\begin{align}
M=\{ (x,y)\in U_{0} \times U_{1}:f_{0}(x)=f_{1}(y) \}
\end{align}$$ Prove $M$ is a manifold without boundary.

For the first one, I have no idea to prove the statement. For one direction, if they are transverse, this means that $$\begin{align}
(p;v)=(p; D\alpha(t)u_{1})+(p;Df_{r}(t')u_{2})= (p;\begin{pmatrix}
-\sin t \\ \cos t
\end{pmatrix}u_{1})+(p;\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}u_{2})
\end{align}$$ where $u_{1},u_{2}$ are 2 numberse from $\mathbb{R}$.  I can't see how to get $r \ne \pm 1$ from here. As for the other direction, I have no idea.

For the second one, I consider the map $g(x,y)=f_{0}(x)-f_{1}(y)$, and $M=\{ (x,y):g(x,y)=0 \}$ . According to the theorem, I know, as long as I can show $M$ is not empty and $\text{rank }Dg(x,y)=n$, I can prove $M$ is a $n$ dimensional manifold without boundary.  However, I don't know how to show the rank as $n$. I do know that $$\begin{align}
Dg(x,y)=(Df_{0}(x)  \ \  -Df_{1}(y))
\end{align}$$ which is a $n \times k$ matrix. Here $k=k_{0}+k_{1}$. I think in order to show the rank is $n$, I should use the property that $f_{0},f_{1}$ are transverse.

Any help on this? Thanks!